# Clerk redirecting to localhost after authentication

Tags: next.js, vercel, clerk

On my production site hosted on vercel, after authentication with clerk, it redirects me to localhost. This only happens on the laptop I'm using for development.

If I connect to the production site on another device, it correctly redirects me back to the production site hosted on vercel after authentication.

I'm following a tutorial for the t3 stack here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkOSUVzOAA4

I'm new to this stack and using nextJS + vercel + clerk so I'm not sure where to even begin. I'll upload any needed code. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this same problem, no idea what's causing it. Also are you getting an issue where the posts aren't displaying? I'm having an issue with the api.posts.getAll.useQuery() call where it's just returning data: undefined and isLoading: true and never resolving. It's driving me insane, I followed the tutorial word for word and it's not working

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm new to the stack, but I followed the tutorial and it was working for me. I changed the root.ts and added a posts.ts

Comment: Turns out it was my Chrome version. Not sure what was going on but just gave it an update and things started working fine -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow Clerk's Next.js setup instructions and it should help get it working. Specifically adding a sign-in and sign-up page and creating these environment variables:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/
```

That should get things working on the Vercel deploy without the weird redirection issue.

https://clerk.com/docs/nextjs/get-started-with-nextjs

Answer (score 0):

I did not have your issue but my issue was implementing my own /sign-in page. Don't do that unless you really want to, use Clerk's sign in page. I should not have done that. The proper way is to make authentication needed on all routes except the home / route. There can be a button on it that links to another page. Clerk will see that page requires auth, redirect you to clerk's sign in page, you sign it, then it redirects you back to the page you wanted to go to.

If you implement your own /sign-in page then there's a bit of extra work involved, this shows how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYUa8FRq2k8